# multiple inputs into same string c++

Tags: c++, sentinel

I'm attempting to write a c++ program that prompts for several 1 word inputs until a sentinel value is inputted. Once this value, (i.e. "done"), is inputted, the program should output all the words that the user inputted.

I have the general format; however, this doesn't store multiple values for the string...any help would be great, thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string word;
    word = "";
    cout << "Enter the next bla bla now:   " ;
    cin >> word;


    while ( word != "complete" )
    {
        cout << "The previous bla bla was:  " << word << endl;
        cout << "Enter the next bla bla now: ";
        cin >> word;

    }

    cout << "Your phrase..bla bla bla is :  " << word << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need some kind of collection type.  `std::vector` would be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the tip :) I will Google for a bit to learn more about that...it hasn't been addressed in our class yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the results into a vector and then loop through them like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::string str;
    std::vector<std::string> strings;
    while(std::getline(std::cin,str) && str != "complete") {
        strings.push_back(str);
    }
    std::cout << "Your strings are: \n";
    for(auto& i : strings)
        std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

What this code does is keep asking for the user input until the word "complete" is found, and it keeps inserting the strings inputted into a vector container. After the word "complete" is inputted, the loop ends and it'll print out the vector's contents.

Note that this uses the C++11 for-range loop, which can be replaced by using iterators or `std::copy` with `std::ostream_iterator`.

Comment: Hi Rapptz, for some reason my compiler does not like that code. I took a screenshot of the errors --> http://prntscr.com/qx58c <--. Could you please explain a bit more about replacing that with std:copy / std:ostream_iterator? Thank you.

Comment: @user2023949 try compiling with `-std=c++11` flag passed. `std::copy` and `std::ostream_iterator` is shown with billz's code. In order to pass `-std=c++11` flag on Code::Blocks it's usually on your Compiler Options, it's easy to find.

Comment: Aww, that's so cute. It politely asks you to remove `auto`.

Comment: @user2023949, If you're using C::B 12.11, you have `-std=c++11` right in the list. If not, go to `Other options` and type it in. Be sure to remove the others like it, such as `-std=c++0x`.

Comment: Thanks Chris, unfortunately I'm a bit lost with your instructions. I made it to the compiler settings (http://prntscr.com/qx6yp) but I don't see anything like -std=c++11 aywhere.

Comment: @user2023949 it's right there `Have g++ follow C++11 ISO C++ language standards [-std=c++11]`.

Comment: Thanks! This program runs quite differently, which is really interested. For example, it doesn't prompt for an in put, it just waits.

Comment: It's easy to edit to your needs, this is just the skeleton really. This does prompt for an input, there just is no text indicating that there is an input waiting.

Comment: Yup :) I think for this specific task (given my current knowledge) the program by Dan Mayor is probably the most suitable. With the other two programs there are some things that I am not "supposed" to know yet.

Comment: I'd like to learn how this works. Where would I go about inserting the questions to enter an input? Also, when I output, I removed the \n at the end but now the inputs are separated by a space.

Comment: @user2023949 I did a decent explanation on the paragraph after the code. `'\n'` detonates a newline. You could probably modify it a lot more to your own personal needs -- really the program itself isn't inherently complex. You can see [this](http://liveworkspace.org/code/FiKbW$0) for an example program of what you were trying to do earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use a collective string to concat these words together as you go.  In short...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string word;
    string allWords = "";

    word = "";
    cout << "Enter the next bla bla now:   " ;
    cin >> word;


    while ( word != "complete" )
    {
        allWords += word + " ";
        cout << "The previous bla bla was:  " << word << endl;
        cout << "Enter the next bla bla now: ";
        cin >> word;
    }

    cout << "Your phrase..bla bla bla is :  " << allWords << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT

In retrospect, using a vector is more usable later and would allow you iterate through these words for another purpose.  My solution would only be useful if for some reason you wanted to compile these words into a single sentence.

Comment: Hi Dan, the goal here is to actually compile the words into 1 single phrase after the sentinel value is inputted. I'm going to look through all these responses and try to figure out what's going on. Thank you!

Comment: Then it sounds like my hastily created answer here would be what you are looking for.  In practice however the other answers mentioning the vector are what you would really use.  However if this is the problem your class is asking you to overcome they might be trying to get you to come to the conclusion of using a secondary variable and building them together like I showed here.  Hopefully your instructors aren't as narrow sighted as mine where and would accept you learning ahead on your own, but using only the knowledge you have been taught so far this is what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `std::vector<std::string>` to store words, below code works with minor change to your own code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    std::string word;
    std::cout << "Enter the next bla bla now:   " ;

    while (std::cin >> word && word != "complete" )
    {
      words.push_back(word);
      std::cout << "You entered:  " << word << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Your word collection is:  " << std::endl;
    std::copy(words.begin(), words.end(), 
              std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Billz, line 19 "std::ostream_iterator...is giving me an error. It says "error: "ostream_iterator" is not a member of "std" and "error expected primary-expression before '>' token.

Comment: you need to include `#include <iterator>`, see my updated answer

Comment: Thank you :) . I find it interesting how this solution and the one from @Dan Mayor both works. If I am correct, the only difference between the two is that yours doesn't prompt for "Please enter the next word" each time.

Comment: @user2023949, You can add it right before the `cin`: `while ((cout << "blah") && (cin >> word) && (word != "complete"))`